# why don't we use Broadband technology to transmit digital signals ,and use Baseband technology to transmit analog signals?

Tags: digital-communications, analog, baseband

I learn the Broadband technology and baseband technology in this website: https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/networking-tutorials/differences-between-baseband-and-broadband-explained.html

**Broadband** technology uses **analog** signals in data transmission

**Baseband** technology uses **digital** signals in data transmission

I want to ask why don't we use **Broadband** technology to transmit **digital** signals ,and use **Baseband** technology  to transmit **analog** signals ??

I have two thinkings about this:

1.we cannot use Broadband technology to transmit digital signals?if not,why?

2.In fact we can,but we will cost  lots of price

these are two different things,but i don'y know which is right

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's nothing to do here - the cited article is completely wrong, start to finish.

Comment: (also, Shine Sun: you have been working on MIMO channel models. You *know* what baseband is, and that this article isn't right. Your level of understanding is so far above the target audience of that article that I'm really surprised you fell for it!)

Comment: well .my question is why "don't" we,i know  Broadband technology uses analog signals in data transmission,and Baseband technology uses digital signals in data transmission,but know why say if we use Broadband technology to transmit digital signals,what will it happend

Comment: we cannot use Broadband technology to transmit digital signals?if not,why?
or in fact we can,and it will cost us lots of price?these are two different things,and i think you just don't understand what i want to say,but V.V.T does!

Comment: @ShineSun be careful, we compare baseband with passband, and singleband with broadband/wideband. However, "broadband" has lost its original meaning and become purely marketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Broadband technology" is not inherently coupled with "analog signal transmission", as "baseband technology" is not coupled with "digital signal transmission". Both wire cables and optical fiber cables transmit signals in the form of electromagnetic waves, in RF frequency range for a wire medium and in IR/light frequency range for an optical fiber medium.

For digital transmission, the source data are transformed to changes in amplitude/frequency/phase parameters of a generated output signal and then the pulse shaping and filtering operations are performed on this signal. Resulting voltage/current or amplitude/phase waveforms have no sharp rise/fall jumps like those you see on the logic analyzer display. In this way, the resulting waveforms look similar to an analog signal.

In a baseband transmission the signal is sent "as is"; in a broadband transmission a modulator device creates a passband signal from a baseband signal and a carrier. The passband signal frequency is shifted by modulation process and occupies the frequency band around the carrier frequency with the width of the baseband signal spectrum. If the entire channel is used for a baseband transmission, we can use a medium's full bandwidth for the baseband signal. On the other hand, passband techniques allow frequency-division multiplexing, and we can share the channel for multiple concurrent transmissions. The number of subchannels is defined by a medium's full bandwidth divided by a baseband signal spectrum width.

Cable television systems use "broadband technology" for distribution of multiple analog video channels. Digital networks also can use frequency-division multiplexing (the "broadband technology", as your reference calls it). In 1980s, 10BROAD36 Ethernet standard was developed in an attempt to use analog TV cables for Ethernet networking. The 10BROAD36 communication line was even able to share a cable with TV channels. The attempt failed for a number of reasons. What's more, the frequency multiplexing is not a single (and so unavoidable) solution for sharing communication lines in packet-switching networks of Internet. The sharing of a communication line to multiple data streams is performed with packet switching. Still, frequency-division multiplexing is used in wired (Discrete Multitone Transmission) and wireless (WiFi, OFDM) digital transmissions.

As for analog transmissions in rare survived analog telecom systems, I do not know of analog signals with spectrum that wide as to occupy the entire bandwith of transmission lines. So these systems can safely use frequency multiplexing to share cables for multiple transmissions ("broadband technology", as your reference calls it).